# Groovy's "optional return" semantics

Tags: groovy, return

In Groovy, the [return statement is optional](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_optional_return_keyword), allowing you to write methods like:

```
def add(a, b) {
    a + b
}
```

...which adds `a` and `b` and returns the result to the caller.

However, I'm wondering what the semantics are when the method has multiple return "statements".  For example, in Java you might have:

```
String append(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null) {
        return b;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

This could (hypothetically) be translated to Groovy like:

```
def append(a, b) {
    if (! a) {
        b
    }
    a + b
}
```

However, in this case, how does Groovy know that `b` inside of the `if` statement should be returned?  Or does it not?  I assume that Groovy cannot simply treat any statement whose result is unused as a `return`, correct?  Are there any clearly defined semantics for how the "optional return" feature behaves in this case?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The page you linked (rather tersely) describes the exact semantics:

> Notice that the return statement is optional at the end of methods.

So the `b` in that `if` block would never be returned unless you explicitly returned it. In practice this means that the return value will be the result of the last statement evaluated, so if your example were

```
def append(a, b) {
   if (!a) { b }
   else { a + b }
}
```

Then the result would be `b` if `!a` is `true` and `a + b` otherwise.

The result of a call to a `void` function is `null`, so if the example were

```
def append(a,b) {
   if (!a) { b }
   else { a + b }
   println "debug: $a $b"
}
```

Then `append` would always return `null`.

My own rule of thumb for this is to always use an explicit return statement if the method or closure contains more than one statement. I think relying on the implicit return statement in more complex methods is dangerous since if anyone adds a line to the end of the method they will change the return value even though they most likely didn't intend to.

Comment: Makes sense.  Although what if I had done `else { a + b }`?  In that case, `b` would be at the "end" of the method, because there'd be no executable statements following it.

Comment: I added a couple of additional examples to elaborate on what the optional return semantics mean in practice.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to use return in methods and not bother in closures, but then I'm an old programmer and my eye expects to see all the explicit returns (guardian clauses, early exits and final result). It also helps that my closures tend to the simple, inline variety where the added terseness is appreciated.

Comment: The last expression that is evaluated is implicitly returned. And in fact, this is another (sometimes) misunderstood functional tendency of groovy. In several functional languages, return statements are always implicit. Of course, this does not create confusion there, as an if statement is often an expression.