# In the below code function is returning value of variable a, how is it possible, please explain

Tags: groovy

**In the below code function myprint is returning value of variable a, how is it possible, please explain**

```
class Test {  
    def myprint(){        
        def a = "my"  
        }   
        }
        def test1 = new Test()
        log.info test1.myprint()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy's "optional return" semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925713/groovys-optional-return-semantics)

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering a groovy method without return statement.

Indeed, as stated in [Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-optional-return-keyword.html), as an example, the return statement is not mandatory to end a Groovy method : the result of the last executed instruction is used asmethod return value.

As a consequence, writing

```
def myMethod() {
    def a = "value"
}
println myMethod()
```

will output

```
value
```

Because Groovy interpreter will consider `def a = "value"` as last instruction to be method return value.

However, for clarity reasons, and contrary to groovy commitee, I will suggest you **not** to use that feature, as it make code a little less readable.

Bonus point : this feature really goes well with closures : when calling `[1,2,3].collect { it*2}` will return `[2, 4, 6]` which is really nice.