# Why does Groovy sometimes not require a return type (or even def) on methods?

Tags: groovy

I am asking "why is this possible in Groovy?" for the following two code blocks.  Maybe I should have created two separate questions, but these seem closely related.

First,

```
class Dog 
{
    public speak() {
        return "Bark"
    }
}
```

Notice how `speak()` doesn't have a return type, and I didn't say `def`.  Yet, the code works as if I included `def`.

Second,

```
@interface MyAnnotation {
}

interface Canine{
    @MyAnnotation
    speak()
}
```

Notice how the `speak()` method doesn't have a return type, but it works when I put an annotation on the method.

Why do both of these code blocks work (i.e., no errors when I use them)? Why does the first one work iff I put `public` before it, and why does the second one work iff I put an annotation on it? And where is this documented?

EDIT:

Here is a runnable script that demonstrates both oddities:

```
@interface MyAnnotation { }

interface Canine{
    @MyAnnotation 
    speak()
}


class Dog implements Canine
{
    public speak() {
        return "Bark"
    }
}

Dog fido = new Dog()
println fido.speak()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy's "optional return" semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925713/groovys-optional-return-semantics)

Comment: @Opal: No, they're asking a totally different question.  If you read carefully, you'll see that the OP for that question used `def` for return types.  In my example, there is *no return type at all,* and thus my question is why this code compiles successfully.

Comment: could you please provide a runnable example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I think you can read this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152405/when-to-write-an-explicit-return-statement-in-groovy and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925713/groovys-optional-return-semantics

Comment: @olyv: Maybe I need to word my question differently...but you really should be able to see that those are different questions than mine.  Your first link is talking about the *optional return statement*, which is not what I'm asking.  As per your second link, if you scroll up, you'll see that Opal already linked to that, and I pointed out that that is a completely different question. I went ahead and changed my question title to "Why does Groovy sometimes not require an explicit return type on methods?" to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy is designed to be flexible and permissive. As long as you use either def, a return type, public, or an annotation, and you have `()` at the end (and the name doesn't match the enclosing class), the interpreter figures out that it's a method declaration and it lets you do it. If you don't care about the return type enough to indicate it, Groovy is also fine with not caring about it. That's the design philosophy.

This syntax isn't documented anywhere I can find. I would guess that indicates this syntax is subject to change. I would hesitate to rely on this and would stick to using def or a return type, if only for the sake of clarity.